# Google Spreadsheets automatically removes leading zeroes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I have a column comprised exclusively of numbers. Whenever I add **050**, the sheet automatically changes it to **50**. I have tried prepending a <kbd>space</kbd>, but it makes no difference.

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If there's a difference between `50` and `050`, what you have are `strings` (i.e. text).

Changing the cell format to `Plain Text` via `Format`>`Numbers`>`Plain Text` will keep leading zeros.

Comment: was wondering why you did not post it as an answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I realised that posting as a comment would leave the question showing as 'unanswered' so best to do it properly :]

Answer (score 36):

Since @jam 's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35527/78352) there might be some improvement in Spreadsheet's features.

If you'd like to preserve and use the numbers as figures (e.g., automatic fill) you might apply the settings from the

```
Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format...
```

menu, and set the pattern to `000`, where the number of zeros represent the number of digits to which the completion will be made with the leading zeros.

Comment: Yes, this is in the "new" Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: This method allows you to continue to use them as numbers

Answer (score 8):

A quicker way of formatting a cell as text, is to add a preceding apostrophe to your number.
In a cell, type

```
'050
```

and it will be interpreted as the string `050`.

Another option is to write it as a formula:

```
="050"
```

Comment: Does not work if it is a formula, as this will display the formula, not the result of the formula

Comment: @davea0511 That is kind of the point - to display the _text_ `050`, not any interpretation of it.

Comment: This is the only solution without changing the properties of the cells manually. Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to have a leading zero on the current month of the year for creating a custom date code I use on my invoices. This is what I did:

```
=IF(LEN(MONTH(TODAY()))=1;CONCATENATE(0,MONTH(TODAY()));MONTH(TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for a way to add a leading zero to a time cell, select "Custom number format" from the dropdown and set this value:

```
hh":"mm":"ss
```

Answer (score -2):

You can format the contents of the cell as `Plain Text`.

An external link failed. Answer as suggested in a comment by @RickyClarkson:

- Select the cell(s),
- Go to Format -> Number -> Plain Text.

Comment: Why can't you put the instructions here in this answer? What happens when that link stops working?

Comment: It has now stopped working. It looks like you need to select the cell(s), then go to Format -> Number -> Plain Text.