# Trailing zeros in Google Spreadsheet automatically removed from form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-form-submissions

When I submit a Google form field with a value of 0.0 or 1.0, the 0 after the decimal is omitted in the spreadsheet results.
When I submit number other than trailing zero, e.g., 1.5 , it posts fine as 1.5 in the spreadsheet.

I tried to select and preformat blank cells (Format->Number) in the spreadsheet where these trailing zeros would appear, but Google is not saving the number formatting on blank cells. It defaults to Automatic.

Any suggestions how to stop spreadsheet from removing the trailing zeroes? Right now I have to add them manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leading zeros in Google Spreadsheet automatically removed](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35526/leading-zeros-in-google-spreadsheet-automatically-removed)

Comment: @Rubén It appears this question is about __trailing__ zeros, despite its title.

Comment: @zaq: The point is that spreadsheets handle values in a different way than databases, almost all values that looks like a number are treated as numbers and the default number formatting is applied by default :)

Comment: @Rubén  I don't see this being an answer in the linked post. Moreover, this question is about __form submission__, which takes the accepted answer "format the cell as plain text" out of the picture - form submission creates new cells with default formatting.

Comment: @zaq: Would you like to improve the question?

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep trailing zeroes of 1 to the 1.0 you just have to klick "Increase Decimal Place"

In order to remove trailing zeroes of 1.0 to the normal 1 you just have to set the number format back to "Automatic"

Answer (score 0):

Basically this question is about how to format form responses submitted to Google spreadsheet

A form submission inserts a new row at the end of the sheet data range and this new row inherits the defaults number format settings.

Things to try:

- Apply the desired format to the whole column not just to cells that actually contain data.
- Delete all the blank rows below the data range
- Use script to format the newly inserted row or the whole data rage.

The related questions have answers that include scripts that could help you as a starting point.

Related

- [How do you automatically align incoming form responses in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62583/88163)
- [How to automatically wrap text to new responses from a form in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88543/88163)